# What is a good text editing library for react-native?

Tags: react-native, text-editor

I'm looking for a text editing library, but i can't find anything, maybe somebody with experience can help me.

I tried to use `rich-editor` but couldn't get it to work.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Mind sharing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For React Native Application you can used **react-native-wordpress-editor**
Installing **react-native-wordpress-editor**

```
npm install react-native-wordpress-editor --save
or 
yarn add react-native-wordpress-editor
```

For more use this link
https://github.com/wix/react-native-wordpress-editor
For build rich text editor you can use draft.js build by facebook for react web application.

**Install draft.js in our react application**

```
npm install --save draft-js
or
yarn add draft-js
```

**Simple Example of using draft.js in your project.**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyEditor />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: OP was asking about react-native specifically. Does Draft.js work with RN at all?

Comment: react-native-draftjs-render will work well in react-native. Follow the following url.
https://github.com/globocom/react-native-draftjs-render

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely try this https://github.com/eneskarpuz/react-native-drag-text-editor
You can ;

- Add multiple text editors with different props
- Edit & Type
- Drag and Drop
- Resize